# How could d-heap perform insert and delete in O(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, tree, heap, priority-queue

I'm studing priority queue and d-heap to implement this data structure.
I've found this data type definition:

> **class DHeap implements PriorityQueue**:
>   ***data***:
>   a d-heap T containing n nodes; each node contains an element (elem) and a key (key) taken from an ordered universe.
>   ***operations***:
>   *findMin()* -> elem 	 T(n) = O(1)
>   *insert(elem e, key k)* 	 T(n) = O(log n)
>   creates a new node v with element e and key k, makes it a leaf of T and restore the ordering rules.
>   *delete(elem e)* T(n) = O(d * log n)
>   exchanges the node v containing the element with any leaf u on the last level of T, then deletes v and restores the ordering rule pushing the node u to its correct position.
>   *decreaseKey(elem e, key d)* T(n) = O(log n)
>   *increaseKey(elem e, key d)* T(n) = O(d * log n)

I omitted full details of the operations, because my question is focused on how can delete performs deletions in d*log n and inserts in log n.

I understood that d - 1 is the time to look for smaller or bigger nodes key between the children of a node in the path root-leaf and log n is the height of the tree, so d*log n is the cost of the comparisons in worst case.
But, how can i find the node that contains an element in d*log n?
I think that this operation requires O(n) (time to visit the heap) and the operation cost ignores that detail. Am i wrong?

Another question is: how can i insert a node as leaf in a linked-based tree? Do I need some pointers to missing leafs? But how can i handle the deletions that releases positions?

Hoping to receive a reply, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, how can i find the node that contains an element in d*log n? I think that this operation requires O(n) (time to visit the heap) and the operation cost ignores that detail. Am i wrong?

For an efficient implementation, you need an auxiliary data structure that stores the map from elements to nodes.

> Another question is: how can i insert a node as leaf in a linked-based tree? Do I need some pointers to missing leafs? But how can i handle the deletions that releases positions?

The simple answer is to use an array, as in binary heaps. Alternatively, you could <strike>augment the heap nodes to point to their leftmost null child, so that finding the next leaf would be O(log_d n)-time.</strike> maintain a pointer to the next leaf, maintaining the complete d-ary tree structure as needed.

Comment: I disagree with you on saying you need an auxiliary data structure. D-ary heap is supposed to be an in-place data structure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap

Comment: @noMAD Not with that API.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but storing an additional data structure is not redundant? Using array is simple and i think that all works well with positional tree representation, with linked based representations makes problems. However, using pointer to other leafs seems nice, thank you.

Comment: @Loki88 We need another data structure because of the operations involving an element argument. Binary heaps have the same problem. If you look at the [C++ `priority_queue` type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/), it omits those operations so as not to have the additional overhead.

Comment: Thank you, now it's all clear.

I can keep an hashtable (as example) with all elements in the queue as key and pointers to the node as value, so that searches cost O(1).

I can also keep a list, where each element is a pointer to a node that leaks a leaf.
When i insert an element, i take the first pointer and append the node, if the parent has d children i delete the pointer, then i push to the end the pointer to the new node.
When i delete a node, if the parent has d child i push to the beginning of the list a new pointer to it.
So insert a node costs O(1) keeping order O(log_d n). Works?